# VSCode gets disconnected from remote container constantly

Tags: docker, vscode-remote

I have a setup to work remotly in a vm inside a container and I have been working with these setup for several months. I followed this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-tutorial) to setup my client environment.

Today it got disconnected when I removed the container (because I was building a new one), and since that moment I can't connect to work. I get connected and instantly I get disconnected. I tried several things

- I closed and opened the Visual Studio Code
- I restarted the computer
- I did a `docker system prune` (both client and server)
- I removed lot of docker images that were not being used
- I already deleted and created a new container

The container is working, the problem is that I am getting constantly disconnected with VSCode from the container

In the logs I can read

```
[23918 ms] Start: Run in container: set -o noclobber ; mkdir -p '/home/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/home/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.installExtensionsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[24517 ms] 
[24517 ms] 
[24517 ms] Exit code 1
[24518 ms] Start: Run in container: for pid in `cd /proc && ls -d [0-9]*`; do { echo $pid ; readlink -f /proc/$pid/cwd ; xargs -0 < /proc/$pid/environ ; xargs -0 < /proc/$pid/cmdline ; } ; echo ; done 2>/dev/null
[25583 ms] Extension host agent is already running.
[25583 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /home/root/.vscode-server/bin/58bb7b2331731bf72587010e943852e13e6fd3cf/.devport 2>/dev/null
```

I think that maybe that `Exit code 1` can be telling that something is not right

Comment: ever figured out what the root cause of this was?

Comment: @mike01010 sorry, it was three years ago; I can't remember. I am unsure about this, but we updated the SSH configuration, which was the fix.